# craft()->locale->getTimeFormat() throws Fatal error

Tags: control-panel, localization, error-message

When requesting the control panel I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimeFormat() on a non-object in
/craft/app/etc/requirements/RequirementsChecker.php on line 103
```

Apparently  `craft()->locale` is null, but I have no idea why this is the case. I'm running craft locally, on http://[PROJECT].craft.dev/ and installed the Pro version.

Any ideas?

Edit: this turned out to be a too restrictive gitignore file, ignoring the craft/app/framework/i18n/data folder

Comment: That is weird.  Can you hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com so we can look into it?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.  Would you mind posting that as an official answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In our case it were the i18n and the vendor files that were being excluded by a too restrictive gitignore file.

Never use the default gitignore from Craft 3 on a Craft 2 setup. :-)